# Display checkbox values on select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('input[name="accounts"]').on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="accounts"]:checked').each(function() {
    if (index == 0) {
      txt = $(this).val();
      $("#accounts-text").html(txt);
    } else {
      $("#accounts-text").append(txt);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><b>Accounts</b></label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Gmail"> Gmail
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Facebook"> Facebook
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Instagram"> Instagram
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Accounts: </label>
  <h5 id="accounts-text"></h5>
</div>
```

In the above code,help me to find out the error while trying to display the check box values on select in the same page.

Comment: Do you want to display all checked values on `#accounts-text`?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all the checked values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to get all values. This will return the array of all checked values. Use `join()` to convert the array into string.

```js
$('input[name="accounts"]').on('click', function() {
  var result = $('input[name="accounts"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  $("#accounts-text").html(result.join("<br />"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><b>Accounts</b></label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Gmail"> Gmail
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Facebook"> Facebook
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Instagram"> Instagram
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Accounts: </label>
  <h5 id="accounts-text"></h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what map() actually does here and why we have to convert array into string ?

Comment: `map()` loop thru the jQuery object and translates all items. In this case, it returns the value.

Comment: The `get()` part is converts it to an array.

Comment: Thankful for your explanation.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$('input[name="accounts"]').on('click', function() {
          var txt  = [];
            $.each($("input[name='accounts']:checked"), function(){            
                txt.push($(this).val());
            });
            //alert("out puts are: " + txt.join(", "));
            $("#accounts-text").html(txt.join("<br />"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><b>Accounts</b></label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Gmail"> Gmail
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Facebook"> Facebook
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="Instagram"> Instagram
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Accounts: </label>
  <h5 id="accounts-text"></h5>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly the function push() does here ?